# How to send a request POST on linux

Tags: linux, bash, post, console

I want to make a POST request from `Linux console` but I don't know how to do it. 
Basically, I want to post to the following url with these values.

```
Post api :  https://blablabla/api/Device
Payload :
{
               "DeviceId" : "C",
               "TransactionValue" : 192.49,
               "RSSI": 240.40,
               "Time" : "2018-05-04 20:36:06.000"
}
```

The body type needs to be a `JSON` file.
I tried the `curl command` with the different options but it doesn't work.
Someone knows other command I should try or a script ?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Hi, I totally understand what you mean. I'll think about it next time. Cheers mate

Answer (score 3):

Here is Proper cURL request if you want to make direct call cURL command

```
curl -X POST \
  https://blablabla/api/Device \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
               "DeviceId" : "C",
               "TransactionValue" : 192.49,
               "RSSI": 240.40,
               "Time" : "2018-05-04 20:36:06.000"
}'
```

Just replace your original URL, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something similar (without the cache control line) before your example, I have the same result. Which is :  "ssl_handshake returned - PolarSSL: (-0x7780) SSL - A fatal alert message was received from our peer". I don't understand where's the problem come from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget to send data, example:

```
wget --post-data "username=hunter2" http://example.com
```

if you do not wish to save the data to a file, you can use `-O` flag, example:

```
wget --post-data "username=hunter2" http://example.com -O /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've never thought to use wget command. When I try your command. It connects the server, sends the request, but the server answer is :"500 Internal Server Error". Which doesn't let you know what is the error. I'll figure out something with the wget command.